# Shader source code compactor

Tags: glsl, shader

Back at the time when the Internet was expensive and slow, the website authors used all sorts of HTML / JavaScript compression tools that would remove whitespace and shorten the names of variables.

Is there such a tool for GLSL shaders? I was going to write it myself, but then I realized there should be such a tool already out there, yet, I was unable to find one.

Comment: "GLSL compiler error in line 1: ..." Have fun with that. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is [GLSL-unit](https://code.google.com/p/glsl-unit/source/browse/#git/compiler) doing this.

Also a browser version version following this [link](http://glslunit.appspot.com/compiler.html).

Comment: I know that it was not a part of the question, but is it possible to run it from command-line? Otherwise a great find!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/488763/how-to-run-js-file-from-a-command-line-on-windows this might help, you might need to tweak the javascript code a bit still.